# Google Text to Speech not working on samsung galaxy J2, API 23

Tags: android, text-to-speech, samsung-mobile

I am developing an app that makes use of Google Text to speech and runs smoothly on Sony phones but fails when tested on Samsung Galaxy J2 running at API 23 , I had set the tts engine to Google text to speech but still gives an error code -1 which says "generic operation failure".Below is the code segment, pls help ......

```
  textToSpeech= new TextToSpeech(mainActivity, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.UK);

            }
        }
    });
 inta=textToSpeech.speak(visionSpeech,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,"1");
```

Comment: Test putting 'speak' after 'setLanguage'

Comment: With that code you are probably calling `speak()` before the `onInit()` has run. The `speak()` method should be called only after `onInit()` has been called with the status `TextToSpeech.SUCCESS`. At that point the TTS engine is ready to speak.

Comment: I have the same problem. On virtual device it's ok, but on my phone i get ERROR = -1 "Denotes a generic operation failure."

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a stupid solution, but i spent an hour, may be it will be helpful for someone. 
When i initiated TextToSpeech in `public void onInit(int status)`
I was getting status -1 "Denotes a generic operation failure."
Problem: In my phone was not install no one TTS.
Solution:
1. Install [Google TTS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tts)
2. Go to a phone setting tehen system Settings->Language & input.->Text-to-speech output.->preferred engine.
3. Pick google TTS.